# Azure dev ops push Authentication failed [source tree on mac]

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I have set a **dev-ops** user account successfully before, while I'm working fine today I tried to push my code. source tree response is **fatal: Authentication failed**

Early today I successfully push | pull data using source tree

Comment: Have you update the user name and password? You could try to delete the existing GIT record by `keychain access`, check this thread for some details:https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-quot-fatal-Authentication-failed-for-quot/qaq-p/201844

Comment: I think Leo's answer is the accepted one. Thank you! It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I did the below steps ad it got resolved

1. Update SourceTree if there are any updates
2. Remove all visualstudio saved passwords from Tools -> Options -> authentication
3. Restart SourceTree
4. Tools -> Options -> Authentication -> Edit saved password under 'Account', and pass new PAT

That's it.